# Mirror tilde accent

Tags: math-mode, macros, symbols, accents

Does anybody know if there is a "mirror" tilde accent command in any package?
That is, the "wiggling" of the tilde accent going in the other direction.

Something like defining this `\backtilde` command:

```
\newcommand{\backtilde}[1]{\overset{\backsim}{#1}}
```

but not quite. The kerning, sizes, etc... are not the same as with the `\tilde{}` command.

Related to this: a mirror version of the `\vec{}` accentuation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with `{}` on it). Finally, you can also use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 14):

The `accents` package turns out to be useful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents,graphicx}

\newcommand{\backtildeacc}{%
  \raisebox{-1.25ex}[.3ex][0pt]{\reflectbox{\normalfont\char"7E}}%
}
\newcommand{\btilde}[1]{\accentset{\backtildeacc}{#1}}

\begin{document}
$\tilde{A}\btilde{A}$

\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{$\btilde{A}$}\fbox{$\tilde{A}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

***Note*** If the `T1` encoding is used, one needs `"03` instead of `"7E`. The various lengths might need to be adjusted for different font families. For instance, `0.21ex` is the right height instead of `0.3ex` with `lmodern`.

Comment: You might want to [accept this (or another) answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark next to the up/down voting buttons.

Comment: I just found out that if my document also has the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, `\btilde` is too wide. (Actually, I might prefer that wider variant, but it does not match the normal `\tilde`.) And if additionally there is the line `\usepackage{lmodern}`, the `\btilde` is typeset too low, like a strike through the letter. Is there a way to have a `\btilde` which consistently produces the mirrored counterpart of `\tilde`, whether those additional packages are loaded or not?

Comment: @azimut Sorry, I don't think you can automate the thing: as you can see, there are a few lengths set in the code.

Comment: The strange thing is that `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is the culprit. If I load `lmodern` without `[T1]fontenc`, the `btilde` works as expected.

Comment: @azimut When `T1` is used, we need `"03` instead of `"7E`. And slightly shorter height when `lmodern` is the font, `0.21ex` instead of `0.3ex`.

Comment: @egreg Many thanks for looking into this again. With the adjustments you suggested, I can use `\btilde` with `T1` and `lmodern`. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Try `\backsim` from the `amssymb` package.  See the image below

[image]

Comment: I did. This is the command I proposed  within my question, but the results are not equivalent.

Comment: Oh, sorry. What do you mean by *other direction*?

Comment: The direction is OK, is just if you compare putting a \overset{\backsim}{A} with \tilde{A} you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can scale your backsim like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\tilde{A}\]

\[\overset{\backsim}{A}\]

\[\overset{\scalebox{0.5}{$\backsim$}}{A}\]
\end{document}
```

Still not totally the same, but it could be used as workaround...