# How to get an inverted (or reversed) tilde on a math symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, tilde, overset

How can we get a reversed (or inverted) tilde on top of a math symbol, in math-mode?  I'm sure that this reversed tilde does exist in LaTeX (I strongly believe I have seen it before), but I'm yet unable to find it back.  Maybe I have just dreamed...

I've found this answer there: [Mirror tilde accent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141126/mirror-tilde-accent), but it doesn't work well and I'm pretty sure (I may be wrong) that this mirrored tilde accent exists without the need to create such a macro.

Here's a MWE code to play with and have fun:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

Blabla:
    \begin{equation}
        \tilde{t} = t \quad \text{How to get a reversed tilde ?}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Please, don't use the `\sim` or `\backsim` symbol, since they're not very similar to the default tilde accent.

---

**EDIT:**  Just to add some context.  I need to show two similar (but different) coordinates transformations rules: Galilean transformation and Lorentz transformation.  I don't want to use the same tilde accent for both transformations.

Comment: Are you sure the two symbols can be easily distinguished?

Comment: I’m not sure, actually. I need to try it, or else find something else like a double tilde. I don’t have much choice (bar accent and other default accents give an ugly result).

Comment: Apart from the horizontal alignment, that could be fixed, [this is the output (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwvc3.png). I don't think they are sufficiently different so that to be unambiguous, particularly if the reversed tilde is not near to a standard one.

Comment: I would add that this reversed tilde is pretty ugly (looks odd!). Then I have à notation problem !

Comment: How about `\hat` and `\check`?

Comment: It’s a good suggestion. I usually reserve the hat accent to unit vectors and to operators in QM.

Comment: How about Roman letters for the Galilean transformation (using `\tilde` for one of the coordinate systems) and Roman and Greek letters for the Lorentzian transformation? Like in J.J.Ca;;ahan's book *Geometry of spacetime*.